# Have I found a security problem in an API or do I just not understand SSL?

Tags: security, ssl

I'm working on building a set of Python bindings around an XML-based API provided by a vendor.  The vendor requires that all transactions be conducted over SSL.  Using a Linux box, I created a key file and a CSR for my application.  Using their self-service web portal, I then generate a certificate using that CSR.  Both the key file and the certificate are used when making the SSL request to the API.

I'm now working on designing exception classes to make error messages more verbose (and, hopefully,  more useful to developers using my bindings).  Part of my testing has included altering the key file: transpose a couple characters here, replace 4 or 5 with random characters there, etc.  To my surprise, altering the key file had no effect!  As long as I didn't change the total length of it, the API didn't complain about a bad key file.  The only way I was able to throw an error was by swapping in a completely different key from another application.  At that point, the API complained about the Common Name not matching.

Is this normal behavior or has the vendor not properly implemented SSL?

Comment: A few things to check (so that we can figure this out): Does the key file just contain the key and nothing else? Does the certificate file just contain the certificate and nothing else? What format are the files in (if you are uncertain, providing the lines with "BEGIN" in the is sufficient)?

Comment: The two files contain "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" and "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----".  I have noticed that changing a couple of characters towards the end of the file does throw a decryption error (as expected).  However, changing random characters in the middle of the key doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some private key formats are redundant and may be altered without corrupting the key material. In fact, the information you've provided is not enough to make any assumptions. At least some knowledge about the format in which the private key was saved would be handy.

As a matter of fact, authentication with corrupted or wrong key won't go. It is mathematically impossible to authenticate with wrong private key (assuming that server-side part of the protocol works right).

Answer (score 1):

That private key contains Base64-encoded ASN.1 encoding of some big integers, without any CRC check or so on. Also, key identifier is calculated over public key part, not private one. So there is no possibility to check it's validity when some middle bytes will be altered, and the error will be thrown by connecting side when the signature check will fail.